# What does "above the law" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

If I want to say about some corruptionists that the are out of law, meaning that they are defended by the law. If I say that they are **above the law**, does it mean that the laws are not for those people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone or something is **above the law** it means that they are not bound by the law themselves. Usually it is used figuratively, that the law technically applies to them but will, for whatever reason, not be enforced.